# DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL very slow response

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to know why sometimes when I run the `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` command to get the DDL of a package takes too long, however, whether to make any changes to the database, if I ever run after a while runs well. The database is remote, perhaps the network could influence this, but I tried to run other queries and do work well. Do you know any specific reason why this function might be delayed intermittently? This is the second time i face this problem and i'm trying to find the cause.

Comment: My impression always has been that the first execution can take few seconds and any subsequent is usually shorter than 1 sec. Haven't been that curious to make a trace to see what everything is actually executed underneath.

Comment: Perhaps, but I canceled it first execution after 15 minutes, and the second also took more than five minutes(canceled too), however, when I run it in half an hour approximately responds in less than 1 second. This problem has already happened to me once, and was solved in the same way, waiting for a while.

Comment: Maybe run an oracle trace?

Comment: @OldProgrammer can you please explain a bit?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL791

Comment: I see this is for 11g, but in versions 12 and 19, this might be bug 28990738.